# Rewriting file each time script is executing but appending at the same time in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, file-handling, with-statement

So i have a main python script which essentially calls another python script with arguments provided. My question is , each time it loops through files and writes to the file , but it appends when doing so.

If i was to run the script again , providing the same test-data folder , it would append to the file again. I want to be able to at each time i run the script , rewrite the whole file so it is empty and then append each file name to the file. Is this possible ?

My code is as follows for my main script :

```
def get_config():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-d", "--export-date", action="store", required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return [args.export_date]
```

Comment: The problem is you're calling `with open('dates/' + current_day + '.json', 'a') as file`, but it should be `with open('dates/' + current_day + '.json', 'w') as file` if you want it to write the file fresh each time. Having `a` as the second argument in `open` will append, and `w` will write new. See [this doc on open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Comment: @TheStrangeQuark

Actually that will not work. If you take a look at my main.py , it loops through each file and calls the script generate_json.py so doing that will only write one line to the file

Comment: Ahh, I see. Why are you using `os.system` to call the other python script instead of just importing it?

Comment: @TheStrangeQuark

I am passing in arguments with it such as  -p , -e and -d which is required to be passed to generate_json.py. Is there a better way to do this

Comment: Yes, but I'll have to look at the exact syntax for Py2.7. Why are you using Python 2.7 instead of 3.x?

Comment: But to answer your actual question with this post, if you just want to start fresh before you call `os.system(..)`, you can add `open(path, 'w')` before that line and it will erase anything that might already exist in that file.

Comment: Yes that's what i have done and it works. I just tried that before you posted your answer@TheStrangeQuark

Comment: @TheStrangeQuark

What is your suggesstion for os.system

Answer (score 1):

**Update**:
OK, I now understand you want to create a new file every time you run your main script. In this case I would just update the generate_json function:

```
def generate_json(path = get_json_location()):
    open('/path/to/your/file', 'w').close()
    for yml in yml_directory :
        print("Running export for " + yml)
        os.system('python generate_json.py -p' + path + ' -e  yaml/'  + yml + ' -d ' + date)
```

Forget what I said about the following line in your generate_json.py and leave it there with the 'a' argument:

```
with open('dates/' + current_day + '.json', 'a') as file:
```

Comment: When doing so , it will only write one line to the file when changed it from 'a' to 'w'